# Recreational Photon Nonsense

Tags: optics, visible-light, laser, interference, quantum-optics

Using constructive and destructive interference principles, and nothing more than a L.A.S.E.R, an array of mirrors, and any type of prism currently known to science:

Is it possible to build the equivalent of an xor IC?

It must be able to be built in real life, but tolerances/materials do not necessarily need to be commonly available.

Comment: With an ideal LASER (It's an acronym) and ideal mirrors and prism, sure. You can set up a beam splitter and a combiner with spacing so that an AND is out of phase. Someone worked out all the gates using interference patterns from slits. I can't recall where.

Comment: @C. Towne Springer ...I know it's an acronym, but I didn't want people to mistake it for shouting, so I went rogue and made an initalisim.  ... I agree it possible in theory, I guess I was looking for someone to have a setup in mind.  I've got one on paper, but I'm curious to see if someone can do it better.  Physics doesn't have the equivalent of "code golf" ... But that's the idea here. :)

Comment: Going rogue and thinking big is good.......I'll drop by later and see how that idea is workin out for ya.......

Answer (score 2):

Sure, as mentioned in the comments, it is possible to create an XOR. Just build a double-path interferometer (Michelson or Mach-Zehnder would be fine) with a narrow-line, continuous-wave laser (say, HeNe). In-phase, constructive interference gives you OR, out-of-phase, destructive interference gives you XOR. So in principle, you can build an optical logic circuit.

Comment: That's a pretty neat Idea.  I've been trying to figure out a way to use phase to My advantage, but I was not even close to that!  That's actually pretty damned clever.  Thanks!